# Magento 2.1 how to vault a card

Tags: magento2, payment

Anyone out there know how to vault a Braintree card without having to create a payment ?

I need to be able to allow customers to change their card details on a recurring payment. To do so would require creating a new entry in the vault with a new public_hash and gateway_token for braintree.

Ideally i'd like to incorporate the Braintree card form onto a page in the account.

I haven't been able to find anything in the braintree controllers for actually making the requests with card details to the braintree API, so assume this must all be done in JS ?

If anyone could shed some light that would be great.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: no - left magento behind